# What are my options for incorporating country flags into a Rails 4 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Right now I am currently using the [country_select gem](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select) and the [countries gem](https://github.com/hexorx/countries) with a `:country` column in my Users model. I want to use `@user.country` to show the national flag for each @user.

[world-flags gem](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/world-flags) has not been updated in 4 years and is listed as being for Rails 3 and there is almost nothing on StackOverFlow about it.

Or I guess I could download these [flag pngs](http://www.iconspedia.com/pack/country-flags-18) put them in a folder on s3 and do something like this:

```
def flag_url 
  self[country] = /flags/"#{country}".png
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to try this [Flag Sprites](https://www.flag-sprites.com/en_US/) , you can integrate it with `country_select gem` easily, no need to store all flag on server. Hope this will help you. it's just a simple css and one image.